# How to change the URL using rewrite rule in wordpress

Tags: permalinks, urls, rewrite-rules

I have a page named `aircraft-gallery` and I am showing the data in this page from database its working fine.

I have another page named `aircraft-gallery-class` i am sending the data in `?id` variable and receiving that data using GET['id'] than I sending this data to the database for results it is also working fine.

Here is my controller in WordPress function to get id

```
public function view_air_crafts_by_class(){
        //var_dump(get_query_var('id')); //working fine
        //die();
        return $this->air_craft_model->get_air_craft_by_class($_GET['id']);
    }
```

Now my question is simple I have this URL

`http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP Airliner`

and I want this URL

`http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/VIP-Airliner`

I am using  these lines of code in my functions.php file to convert the URL but it's not working, I don't know why

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'aircraft-gallery-class/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=aircraft-gallery-class&id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}
```

I have already tried many codes suggested by the community but it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am clicking saving permalinks every time I update the functions.php file. Thanks

Comment: You have the right idea, although `id` is a very generic variable to use

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `id` is no longer a `$_GET` variable, and is instead a WP query variable, so use the `get_query_var` function instead

Comment: I am new in WordPress that's why I am facing problem how can I use get_query_var could you please help me.

Comment: `echo $_GET['id']` `echo get_query_var( 'id' )`

Comment: could you please solve my issue where I can put this get_query_var...?

Comment: @Komalkhan without seeing the code for your page it's not possible to say, but anywhere you see `$_GET['id']` or `$_REQUEST['id']` needs changing to `get_query_var('id')`

Comment: here is my function in my controller   public function view_air_crafts_by_class(){
  //var_dump($one);
  //echo get_query_var('id');
  //die();
  return $this->air_craft_model->get_air_craft_by_class(get_query_var('id'));
 }

Comment: echo get_query_var( 'id' ) working fine it's fetching the data but facing the same issue URL" aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP%20Airliner "

Comment: get_query_var‌('id') getting the value but my URL still in same position example.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP%20Airliner I always save the Permalink Settings after adding script in functions.php file

Comment: oooh so the rewrite rule works, and visiting `/aircraft-gallery/VIP-Airliner` works but all the permalinks/hyperlinks still refer to `/aircraft-gallery/?id=VIP-Airliner`? Is this `get_permalink()` how are those hyperlinks being generated? Also you should edit your question instead of commenting code so it doesn't get mangled

Comment: please check out my question I have just updated.

Comment: I don't understand, are the links to the page the problem or are you being redirected to the non-pretty permalink? *It's not clear what is happening*, your question asked how to make the rewrite rule work, and by your own admission it works, so there's a piece missing you're assuming I understand, something more it needs to do that you haven't explicitly mentioned. Edit your question and be descriptive including how you're testing that it works and what happens when you test it

Comment: please visit this url http://jetrequest.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP%20Airliner

Comment: I just want this url http://example.com/aircraft-gallery/VIP-Airliner which I sent you above

Comment: @Komalkhan I don't understand, that's not a rewritten URL, that's your old URL, are you expecting it to be magically redirected to the pretty one? Do you have any redirects already in place? If so they should be mentioned in your question as they complicate the process greatly

Comment: have you visit the current site...? if not please visit now http://jetrequest.com/aircraft-gallery/aircraft-gallery-class/?id=VIP%20Airliner

Comment: @Komalkhan you gave me a non-pretty URL, and I arrived at a non-pretty URL, I don't understand, are you expecting to be redirected to the pretty URL? I get the feeling you have not fully stated what you expect to happen and are just sending me the link assuming I will understand, but I do not

Comment: I sent you a non-pretty url but I want a pretty url that's why I add these lines of code in my functions.php file add_filter( 'query_vars', 'wpa5413_query_vars' );
function wpa5413_query_vars( $query_vars )
{
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpa5413_init' );
function wpa5413_init()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'aircraft-gallery-class/([^/]+)/?',
        'index.php?pagename=aircraft-gallery-class&id=$matches[1]',
        'top' );
}

Comment: ooooh so you *do* want it to redirect from non-pretty to pretty, that's not what rewrite rules do, rewrite rules don't redirect, they translate pretty URLs into non-pretty ones so that you don't have to see the ugly bits. You'll need to implement the redirect yourself. You'll also need to eliminate the spaces in your IDs and replace them with dashes or you'll have a lot of problems. You also appear to have something that's checking for the GET parameter and redirecting to the homepage, breaking your rewrite rule

Comment: could you please guide me how can I achieve this I am facing this problem  because I am new in WordPress